# Yii2 add image,css,js files from vendor folder on page from js script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, yii2

I try to create lib for editing pictures. I have main js file for including all other js, css and images files. For example, I used:

```
$.getScript(site_url + '/vendor/first_folder/second_folder/assets/js/script.js');
```

I read that path for web sets at AppAsset.php, if I will ask change @webroot to @vendor.. at extention configuration I think it will be wrong. I created my MyAsset.php and set there such configurations:

```
namespace app\vendor\first_folder\second_folder;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class EdikEditorAsset extends AssetBundle {

    public $sourcePath = '@vendor/first_folder/second_folder/assets/';
    public $css = [
         'css/main.css'
    ];
    public $js = [      
        'js/jquery.colorbox-min.js',      
        'js/main.js'        
    ];   
}
```

But I cannot include others js, css and image files from my extention, because all js,css and images start including from web folder and I don't know how go do above. What can I change for including js, css, images files from vendor folder?

P.S. 
I tried to change using different paths this part in js, but noone worked, so I think problem not in this:

`$.getScript(site_url + '/vendor/first_folder/second_folder/assets/js/script.js`);

Comment: is the vendor folder accessible on web?

Comment: No, vendor is in a site folder.

Comment: All files that you want to be accessible to client should be in web accessible directory. If they are not client would never access them.

Answer (score 3):

Vendor folder is not web accessible.  One solution is to symlink the css, js, img from vendor folder into the web folder.  Then include that.  Or here is the Yii way to do it:

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class BootstrapAsset extends AssetBundle {

//set the source path using @vendor or another alias like @bower here
  public $sourcePath = '@bower/bootstrap/dist';

//include css and js relative to the source path set above
  public $css = [
    'css/bootstrap.css',
  ];
  public $js = [
    'js/bootstrap.min.js',
  ];
}
```